# Stepper motor torque calculation based on pulleys ratio

Tags: stepper-motor

Say a stepper motor has fixed value of "`units`", given as a holding torque related to distance of the center of its shaft. Like **1kg/cm** or **14oz/inch**.

I have a GT2 16-teeth pulley on the motor shaft. (I'm using a 5mm GT2 belt as a load transfer if that matters) Knowing that the motor can hold 1kg weight, 1cm away of the center of its shaft, and the 16-teeth pulley "outher-teeth" diameter is 9.7mm, I can easily assume that it can hold about 1kg of load safely (at least trusting manufacturer's datasheet).

But, what if I add a GT2 48-teeth pulley on the load part (I don't know the outer diameter)?

Is there any algorithm I could use (to atleast *roughly*) calculate load capabilites of the motor, based only on the pulley teeth count?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Circumference is a fixed ratio (π) times the diameter. Therefore the number of teeth is in proportion to the diameter.

If everything is 100% efficient then the torque will step up by the pulley ratio. 1 kg·cm with 16 teeth on the motor and 48 on the load will give 3 kg·cm available on the load.

Note that torque is force **times** distance so it's kg·cm, not kg/cm.